# Snap dragged mouse position perpendicular to start edge in 3D

Tags: math, vector, 3d

I'm drawing a line as I drag my mouse from an edge **AB** in 3D, using the vector that the mouse's path creates to draw the line **CD** - see the image. I need to determine whether the line **CD** is perpendicular to **AB** and if not how I move it to a position where it is perpendicular **CE**.

[Perpendicular Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJ8If.jpg)

I can determine the angle of the mouse's path in relation to the edge but I'm struggling to determine where the mouse should be snapped to, to be perpendicular to the edge.

In 2D I could simply determine two vectors that would be perpendicular to the edge (1 on either side of the edge) and compare my mouse path to those but in 3D the possible vectors are infinite, so I need to limit the options somehow.

I can create a triangular plane between points **CBD** but I still don't know the best way to use this to determine a perpendicular vector from the edge **FG**, I only know that my mouse path is or is not perpendicular.

I might be approaching this all wrong, so any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

**Edit:**

I'm not sure if I need to write a new question for this but thought it seemed reasonable to carry on this thread.

I can now drag perpendicular lines from any edge on my geometry using the below answer from **MBo**. However, I now have the issue of infinite perpendicular directions for any given edge.

Is there an easy way to limit these to four directions (see image - green dashed line is mouse path)? I'm showing a cube in the image but it could be any edge geometry in 3D space. [Perpendicular Dragging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NBJO.jpg)

My current thinking is that the best way is to take the edge that the mouse is dragging from and use any connected edges to create a plane, then using the plane's normal limit perpendiculars to that but if there's a better way, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find projection of point `D` onto line `A-B` using vector algebra:

```
AB = B - A   //(AB.x = B.x-A.x and so on)
AD = D - A 
P = A + AB * (AB.dot.AD) / (AB.dot.AB) 
//(AB.dot.AD) = AB.x * AD.x + AB.y * AD.y + AB.z * AD.z
```

Now shift `D` by difference of `C` and `P`

```
E = D + (C - P)
```

Note that when value `t=(AB.dot.AD) / (AB.dot.AB)`  is not in range `0..1`, projection point lies outside of AB segment

Comment: Thanks. I figured this out last night. Was working out angles in 3D to try and solve this but the vector approach is way simpler.